# Random name picker with bounce animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking to create a random name picker with HTML, JS and CSS which has gone quite well as you can see here... http://clients.random.agency/namepicker/

However, the client has asked for it to have a similar animation to this with ...

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3likecb0ld30som/Jv0Gp4XkhQ.mp4?dl=0

I've search google but I can't seem to find any examples of what I'm looking for and would really appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question itself, not just on an external site. Stack Overflow exists to answer questions for lots of people, not just one, and when that linked site goes down, this question loses its usefulness. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) to provide a runnable snippet when you [edit] your question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey thank you for your response. There is no code to provide, what I've done up to now will be discarded as it's not what the client now requires. I was merely providing it as an example of what I'm trying to achieve (minus the animation)

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple example, hope be helpful.

```js
var names =['John', 'David', 'Joe', 'Sara'];
var nameCount= names.length;
var p = document.getElementById("container");

var randTimer = setInterval(function(){ p.innerHTML = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * nameCount)]; }, 200);

function stop(){
clearInterval(randTimer);
}
```

```css
#container{
color: red;
font-size:2rem;
text-align:center;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p id="container" onClick="stop()"></p>
<p>click on random names to pick one!</P>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your comment, I've already created a version that works like this, I'm looking to achieve the animation like in the OP

Comment: Just the thing I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty similar example I was able to find. Using Javascript seems to be the most straightforward way to go about doing this. https://codepen.io/maerianne/pen/pRQbQr

```
var myScrollTop = function(elem, delay){
  elem.animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, delay, function(){
    myScrollBottom(elem, delay);
  });
};

var myScrollBottom = function(elem, delay){
  elem.animate({ scrollTop: elem.height() }, delay, function(){
    myScrollTop(elem, delay);
  });
};
var scrollUpDown = function(elem, delay) {
  myScrollTop(elem, delay);
};


$(document).ready(function(){
  scrollUpDown($(".scroll-up-down"), 5000);
});
```

As you can see, `scrollUpDown()`is the initial function which starts a loop switching between `myScrollTop()` and `myScrollBottom()`. You could pretty easily make the delay increase with each iteration to mimic the slowing down and eventual stop in the example animation you gave.
You could also refactor this to be a singular [recursive function](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-recursive-function/).

Best of luck!

Comment: thank you for your comment. I've had a bit of a play with the codepen, if I set the height of the .list to the height of the element (30px) you only ever see item 1 and 2.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't trying to give you an out of the box solution. You said how you had searched Google and couldn't find any relevant examples so I gave you one that is very similar to what you're trying to do. The reason it's only showing item 1 and 2 is because `myScrollBottom()` scrolls down `elem.height()` pixels. If you change the height of the element to 30px, it will only scroll 30px. Try wrapping the <ul> element in a div element with `height` equal to 300px and `overflow` equal to hidden.

Answer (score 0):

It picks a random item from the array of labels. Then it goes into a loop, changing the label to the next item in the array until it gets to the chosen one, and using animation for the transitions

```js
$('#search_btns button:nth-child(2)').hover(function() {
  
  btnTimeID = setTimeout(function() {
    
    // We are using the math object to randomly pick a number between 1 - 11, and then applying the formula (5n-3)5 to this number, which leaves us with a randomly selected number that is applied to the <ul> (i.e. -185) and corresponds to the position of a word (or <li> element, i.e. "I'm Feeling Curious").
    var pos = -((Math.floor((Math.random() * 11) + 1)) * 5 - 3) * 5
    
    if (pos === -135) {
      console.log("position didn't change, let's force change")
      pos = -35;
    }
    
    $('#search_btns button:nth-child(2) ul').animate({'bottom':pos + 'px'}, 300);
    
    // Change the width of the button to fit the currently selected word.
    if (pos === -35 || pos === -110 || pos === -185 || pos === -10 || pos === -60 || pos === -160) {
      console.log(pos + ' = -35, -110, -185, -10, -60, -160');
      $('#search_btns button:nth-child(2)').css('width', '149px');
    } else if (pos === -85) {
      console.log(pos + ' = -85');
      $('#search_btns button:nth-child(2)').css('width', '160px');
    } else if (pos === -210) {
      console.log(pos + ' = -210');
      $('#search_btns button:nth-child(2)').css('width', '165px');
    } else {
      console.log(pos + ' = -260, -235');
      $('#search_btns button:nth-child(2)').css('width', '144px'); 
    }
  },200);
}, function() {
  
  clearTimeout(btnTimeID);
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('setTimeout function');
    $('#search_btns button:nth-child(2) ul').css('bottom', '-135px'); // this is the original position
    $('#search_btns button:nth-child(2)').css('width', '144px'); // reset the original width of the button
  },200);
});
```

```css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: arial;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
#search_btns {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    padding-left: 60px;
}
#search_btns button:nth-child(2) {
    width: 144px;
}
#search_btns button:nth-child(1) {
    bottom: 12px;
}
#search_btns button {
    position: relative;
    height: 34px;
    margin: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
  color: gray;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#search_btns button:hover {
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
    box-shadow: 0px 0.5px 0px 0px #d3d3d3;
}
#search_btns button:active {
    border: 1px solid #7f7fff;
}

#search_btns button:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

#search_btns button ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 5px 0;
    text-align: left;
}

#search_btns button ul {
    padding-left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -135px;
    width: 144px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="search_btns">
    <button>This might be the effect you looking for</button>
    <button>
      <ul>
         <li>item0/li>
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item2</li>
        <li>item3</li>
        <li>item4</li>
        <li>item5</li>
        <li>item6</li>
        <li>item7</li>
        <li>item8</li>
        <li>item9</li>
      </ul>
    </button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```